# Doe's a boolean modifier is needed for this problem?

Tags: modifiers, boolean-modifier

I'm a Blender novice working on a project of glasses with multiple parts.[image]

My goal is to have the bridge (blue part) cut off by the frame (red part) for a better fit.[image]

I attempted to use the boolean modifier on the blue part, but when I set the red part as the operand, it simply disappears. I've also experimented with different settings, but the transformation doesn't occur.[image]

Is the boolean modifier only effective with simple shapes? If so, are there alternative techniques I can explore to address this issue? Appreciate any guidance or suggestions!

Comment: The modifier should easily cope with simple shapes like that. First check that the Normals are correct by switching on Face Orientation on the Viewport Overlays menu (or pressing F3 and typing in Face Orientation). If they are correct (all blue) you could try switching to the Fast Solver option on the modifier.

Comment: Thank you! Effectivly when I turn on the fast solver it jsut work

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean for this if you want to, but if you need to fill some frame-like thing with something like glass or anything similar, you can also just do only that - fill it. If you have tidy geometry around something that forms a face or edge loop, it's convenient to select that geometry with loop selection tools or insert another edge loop, duplicate it, then separate and fill the new object. You can then extrude resulting plane or use solidify modifier to give it thickness.

[image]

What I do here:

- Select the object and enter edit mode( <kbd>Tab</kbd> )
- Insert new edge loop ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>R</kbd> )
- Separate it from the object using Separate menu and choosing Selection from it( <kbd>P</kbd>  ->  <kbd>S</kbd> )
- Exit edit mode, select the new separated object consisting of only the edge loop, enter edit mode of it(<kbd>Tab</kbd>  )
- It still has all edges selected in edit mode, so I only need to fill it(<kbd>F</kbd> )
- Then I extrude it (<kbd>E</kbd>) and move it up
- I hit <kbd>Numpad /</kbd> to isolate selection in the viewport to be able to see it without any other objects so it's fully visible.

I would normally use bevel modifier for most things to have those bevels that give you highlights on object edges in reality and I would also bevel the newly crated loop and then extrude it inwards to form a groove for the glass, only then make the glass and move the glass edge inwards a tiny bit to prevent z-fighting(around 0.1mm maybe on glasses), because it's transparent and the groove may be visible in some cases through the glass, or at least some effects might be visible in internal reflections and refractions.

[image]

I mean something is definitely going on there at the edge.

Comment: Martynas I don't think it's the glass area that he/she is trying to boolean. It's the green-blue section that is disappearing according to his question and the images.

Comment: Nice extra tips. I have try it and it works very well ! Thank you for taking the time to explain it to me. :)

Comment: @JohnEason You seem to be right. I should have read the text more carefully and got a bit confused by the images.

Comment: @PriseHDMI My answer does not address the actual question, I would like to delete it. I assume, you already got whatever part of it that was useful to you, right?

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys No problem! If it had been me I could have given old age as an excuse... (I was 78 last week.) :^) Anyhow your suggestions seem to have been useful to the poster so I'd leave your reply in place.